# Is there any way to bundle JSON files to Jar file?

Tags: json, gradle

Is there any way to bundle JSON files to Jar file? For example we are using maven-jaxb2-plugin for creating jar from xsd. In similar way i need for Json files. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin) Gradle plugin. According to it's description:

> jsonschema2pojo generates a Java representation of your json schema.
>   The schema reference describes the rules and their effect on generated
>   Java types.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This will work perfectly. But it will create java classes from JSON schemas. Then we need to convert those java classes to jar file. Is there any gradle plugin exists to directly convert json schema files to jar.